# Multiple Windows options in Grub Menu

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

My system has 2 OS: Win 7 x64 and Ubuntu 12.10. I'm getting 2 Windows boot options: "on dev/sda1" and "on dev/sda2". What does this mean? What implications does this have for my continued Windows usage and for when I may remove the Ubuntu installation later?

Longer: I was running just Win 7 x64, then installed Ubuntu 12.10 along side it. Was trying to boot back to Windows 7 only to get a "disc reading error." Booted back to Ubuntu, grabbed boot-repair, then used mbr repair in boot-repair. System could then boot back to Windows but in fact always did so directly, i.e. always by-passed Ubuntu. Then I used the Ubuntu LiveCD to get boot-repair and used the "Recommended" repair option. Now everything works normally except for the issue described here. Both Windows options in Grub boot to the same Win installation I had previously.

p.s. Running "sudo update-grub" maintains both the Windows options.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting 2 Windows boot options: "on dev/sda1" and "on dev/sda2".
>   What does this mean?

Don't worry, what you observe is normal and common.
These 2 Windows entries in the GRUB menu both boot Windows the same way. 
I can tell you how to remove/hide one entry if you indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

> What implications does this have for my continued Windows usage and
>   for when I may remove the Ubuntu installation later?

No bad implication. You can use Windows normally whatever the Windows entry you choose. And you can uninstall Ubuntu in 1 click via [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller).